# Pointers and functions for calculating the squareroot of a number in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, math

Currently working on an school assignment that requires us to write a program that takes user input. As long as the input is positive the squareroot should be calculated, but if the input is negative the squareroot should not be calculated and the program shall print out a message telling the user that its not possible to calculate the squareroot if a negative number.

Quote from the assignment:

"If ​number​ is non-negative, the function should calculate the square root and place theresult in the pointer argument and return the value 1.If ​number​ is negative the function should ​not​ calculate the square root at all, but insteadonly return the value 0."

Here is what i have so far, but when ever I've entered a number the program just shuts down as if it's finished the task but it does not print out anything, help is appriciated. (First programming course i take)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void squareRoot(float number1, float *squareroot)
{


    if (number1 > 0)
    {
        *squareroot = sqrt(number1);
        return 1;
    }
    else if (number1 < 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
int main(void)
{
    float n1;
    printf("Enter a number to calculate the squareroot of the number: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &n1);

    float squareRootResult;
    squareRoot(n1, &squareRootResult);

    if (squareRoot == 1) 
    {
        printf("The squareroot of the entered number is: %f", squareRootResult);
    }
    else if (squareRoot == 0)
    {
        printf("It is not possible to calculate thesquare root of a negative number​");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One issue with your code is your naming conventions. Don't give your functions and variables the same name.

Comment: `return 1;` and `return 0;`?  A `void` function can not return values of any type.

Comment: And from now on, turn warnings of your compiler on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many problems in here, starting with:

You declared the function `squareRoot` to return `void` (ie: ***nothing***).

Then you try to return integers:

```
{ ...return 1;.... return 0;  }
```

Ask yourself how a function that returns nothing should return an `int` of `1` or `0`.

---

#### Fixup:

```
// Change return value to int
int squareRoot(float number1, float *squareroot)
{  [....] }

int main(void)
{
    [...]

    // Declare a variable to hold the return value.
    int retValue;
    float squareRootResult;

    // Put the return value in variable retValue
    retValue = squareRoot(n1, &squareRootResult);

    // Check the value that was returned!
    if (retValue == 1)
    {
        printf("The squareroot of the entered number is: %f", squareRootResult);
    }
    else if (retValue == 0)
    {
        printf("It is not possible to calculate thesquare root of a negative number​");
    }
```

Comment: Changed that, as you said I asked myself how something that returns nothing would be able to return an int. Thanks

Comment: Tried to run the code after I added/changed what you said and the program now works. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

`squareRoot` is the address of the function, not any particular return value of the function. Didn't your compiler warn of you of this in any way? The fact that it apparently compiles a `void` function with integral return values is a concern too. Perhaps now might be a good time to (i) see if you can get the compiler to warn you of such things, or (ii) convince your school to upgrade to a newer one. Like love and nature, excellent C compilers are available for free.

The address of the function is not allowed to be 0 by the C standard (ignore this technicality for now), and it's very likely not 1 either, hence neither `if` statement conditional evaluates to 1, and this accounts for the lack of output.

Your best bet is to perform the validation check on the input `n1` *before* attempting to evaluate the square root. Don't forget to check the return value of `scanf_s` too - it should be 1 if a `float` value was read successfully from standard input.

Comment: ...and to turn warnings of the compiler on. (Any question/error that could have been prevented if warnings were turned on should be punishable with a downvote of the question)

Comment: The code does not return errors tho, if I for example remove a ";" I would get and error/warning

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: Although it wouldn't be the first time that a school used a C compiler from the 1970s.

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking the right thing:

```
squareRoot(n1, &squareRootResult);

if (squareRoot == 1) 
{
    printf("The squareroot of the entered number is: %f", squareRootResult);
}
else if (squareRoot == 0)
{
    printf("It is not possible to calculate thesquare root of a negative number​");
}
```

`squareRoot` is the actual function, not the return value.  What you're actually doing is checking if the function's pointer is 1 or 0.

You need to assign the return value of the function a another variable and check that.

```
int rval = squareRoot(n1, &squareRootResult);

if (rval == 1) 
{
    printf("The squareroot of the entered number is: %f", squareRootResult);
}
else if (rval == 0)
{
    printf("It is not possible to calculate thesquare root of a negative number​");
}
```

Also, you need to change the definition of `squareRoot`:

```
void squareRoot(float number1, float *squareroot)
```

In the function you attempt to return a value but the function is declared to not return anything.  You need to set the return type to `int`:

```
int squareRoot(float number1, float *squareroot)
```

Finally, your `squareRoot` function doesn't handle the case where `number1` is 0 and will fail to return a value.  This can be fixed by changing this:

```
if (number1 > 0)
```

To:

```
if (number1 >= 0)
```

Comment: `squareRoot` is declared `void`.  It cannot return values.

Comment: @abelenky Yes, it missed that at first.  Fixed.